# Make parameter unique in laravel request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

hello I have a table called gallery_category_contents

| language | title | gallery_category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| en | FISH | 1 |
| en | DOGS | 2 |

and my request rules are like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "language"=>[
            "required",
            Rule::unique('gallery_category_contents','language')->ignore($this->gallery_category_id,'gallery_category_id')
        ],
        "title"=>[
            "string",
            "required"
        ]
    ];
}
```

what i want is that it doesn't add already existing language with same gallery_category_id

For example, English language has been added to 1 gallery_category_id, so it should not be added again. my current code works, but it affects all the data in that table, that is, it also affects category 2

how to do it?

Comment: Please complete your question with the following: what have you already tried (show us the code)?; what exactly didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'gallery_category_id' => [
            'required',
            Rule::exists('gallery_category'),
        ],
        'language' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('gallery_category_contents', 'language')
                ->where('gallery_category_id', $this->input('gallery_category_id')),
        ],
        'title' => [
            'required',
            'string',
        ]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own validation rule:

`php artisan make:rule CompositeUnique`

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Rules;
 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
 
class CompositeUnique implements Rule, DataAwareRule
{
    private array $data;
    private array $columns;
    private $model;
    private $ignoreId;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @param $model
     * @param string|array $colums
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($model, $columns, $ignoreId)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->columns = (array)$columns;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $this->model::query()
            ->where($this->columns, array_reduce(function($where, $column) {
                $where[$column] = $this->data[$column];
                return $where;
            }, [])
            ->where($this->model->getKeyName(), $this->ignoreId)
            ->doesntExist();
    }
 
    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be unique.';
    }

    /**
     * Set the data under validation.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```php
use App\Rules\CompositeUnique;
use App\Models\GalleryCategoryContents;

//...

new CompositeUnique(
    GalleryCategoryContents::class,
    [ 'language' 'gallery_category_id' ],
    $this->gallery_category_id
);`
```